# App crash on first load using SQLiteAssetHelper

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I get the following error during the first launch after install of the app then later the app launch normally without issue.

```
> > 06-29 14:56:20.811 19467-19467/com.domain.sample E/SQLiteLog: (14) cannot open file at line 36667 of [0c55d17973]
>     (14) os_unix.c:36667: (2) open(/data/user/0/com.domain.sample/databases/quotes.sqlite3) -  06-29
> 14:56:20.812 19467-19467/com.domain.sample E/SQLiteDatabase: Failed to
> open database
> '/data/user/0/com.domain.sample/databases/quotes.sqlite3'.
>     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14 SQLITE_CANTOPEN): Could not open database
>         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
>         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:211)
>         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:195)
>         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:503)
>         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:204)
>         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:196)
>         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:880)
>         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:865)
>         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:766)
>         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:714)
>         at com.domain.sample.database.ExternalDbOpenHelper.checkDataBase(ExternalDbOpenHelper.java:93)
>         at com.domain.sample.database.ExternalDbOpenHelper.createDataBase(ExternalDbOpenHelper.java:70)
>         at com.domain.sample.database.ExternalDbOpenHelper.openDataBase(ExternalDbOpenHelper.java:133)
>         at com.domain.sample.database.ExternalDbOpenHelper.<init>(ExternalDbOpenHelper.java:48)
>         at com.domain.sample.database.ExternalDbOpenHelper.getInstance(ExternalDbOpenHelper.java:32)
>         at com.domain.sample.loader.AbstractQueryLoader.<init>(AbstractQueryLoader.java:14)
>         at com.domain.sample.loader.QuoteGroupLoader.<init>(QuoteGroupLoader.java:17)
>         at com.domain.sample.QuoteGroupActivity.onCreateLoader(QuoteGroupActivity.java:154)
>         at android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl.createAndInstallLoader(LoaderManagerImpl.java:370)
>         at android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl.initLoader(LoaderManagerImpl.java:404)
>         at com.domain.sample.QuoteGroupActivity.onCreate(QuoteGroupActivity.java:107)
>         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7131)
>         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7122)
>         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2882)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3037)
>         at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
>         at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
>         at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1797)
>         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6642)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>         at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 06-29
> 14:56:20.812 19467-19467/com.domain.sample
> E/class com.domain.sample.database.ExternalDbOpenHelper: Error while
> checking db 06-29 14:56:20.812 19467-19467/com.domain.sample
> W/SQLiteAssetHelper: copying database from assets... 06-29
> 14:56:20.813 19467-19467/com.domain.sample W/SQLiteAssetHelper:
> extracting file: 'quotes.sqlite3'... 06-29 14:56:20.847
> 19467-19467/com.domain.sample W/SQLiteAssetHelper: database copy
> complete 06-29 14:56:20.869 19467-19467/com.domain.sample
> I/SQLiteAssetHelper: successfully opened database quotes.sqlite3 06-29
> 14:56:20.870 19467-19467/com.domain.sample I/Jalal: copyDataBase()
> 06-29 14:56:20.870 19467-19467/com.domain.sample D/AndroidRuntime:
> Shutting down VM
> 
> > --------- beginning of crash 06-29 14:56:20.870 19467-19467/com.domain.sample E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>     Process: com.domain.sample, PID: 19467
>     java.lang.Error: Error copying com.domain.sample.database!
>         at com.domain.sample.database.ExternalDbOpenHelper.createDataBase(ExternalDbOpenHelper.java:78)
>         at com.domain.sample.database.ExternalDbOpenHelper.openDataBase(ExternalDbOpenHelper.java:133)
>         at com.domain.sample.database.ExternalDbOpenHelper.<init>(ExternalDbOpenHelper.java:48)
>         at com.domain.sample.database.ExternalDbOpenHelper.getInstance(ExternalDbOpenHelper.java:32)
>         at com.domain.sample.loader.AbstractQueryLoader.<init>(AbstractQueryLoader.java:14)
>         at com.domain.sample.loader.QuoteGroupLoader.<init>(QuoteGroupLoader.java:17)
>         at com.domain.sample.QuoteGroupActivity.onCreateLoader(QuoteGroupActivity.java:154)
>         at android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl.createAndInstallLoader(LoaderManagerImpl.java:370)
>         at android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl.initLoader(LoaderManagerImpl.java:404)
>         at com.domain.sample.QuoteGroupActivity.onCreate(QuoteGroupActivity.java:107)
>         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7131)
>         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7122)
>         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2882)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3037)
>         at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
>         at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
>         at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1797)
>         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6642)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>         at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 06-29
> 14:56:20.882 19467-19467/com.domain.sample I/Process: Sending signal.
> PID: 19467 SIG: 9
```

---

Here is the class :

```
public class ExternalDbOpenHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {
    //Path to the device folder with databases
    public static String DB_PATH;
    //Database file name
    public static final String DB_NAME = quotesDatabaseInfo.DB_NAME;
    public static final int DB_VERSION = quotesDatabaseInfo.DB_VERSION;

    private static ExternalDbOpenHelper sInstance;

    public SQLiteDatabase database;
    public Context context;


    public static ExternalDbOpenHelper getInstance(Context context) {

        if (sInstance == null) {
            sInstance = new ExternalDbOpenHelper(
                    context.getApplicationContext(), DB_NAME);
        }

        Log.i("Jalal", "ExternalDbOpenHelper getInstance(Context context)");
        return sInstance;
    }

    private ExternalDbOpenHelper(Context context, String databaseName) {

        super(context, databaseName, null, DB_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
        Log.i("Jalal", "ExternalDbOpenHelper(Context context, String databaseName)");
        //Write a full path to the databases of your application
        String packageName = context.getPackageName();
        //DB_PATH = String.format("//data//data//%s//databases//", packageName);
        DB_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir +"/databases/";
        openDataBase();


    }

    public ExternalDbOpenHelper(Context context){
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);

        Log.i("Jalal", "ExternalDbOpenHelper(Context context)");
    }

    public SQLiteDatabase getDb() {
        Log.i("Jalal", "SQLiteDatabase getDb()");
        return database;
    }




    //This piece of code will create a com.domain.sample.database if it’s not yet created
    public void createDataBase() {
        Log.i("Jalal", "createDataBase()");
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
        if (!dbExist) {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            //this.getWritableDatabase();

            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying com.domain.sample.database!");
            }
        } else {
            Log.i(this.getClass().toString(), "Database already exists");
        }
    }

    //Performing a com.domain.sample.database existence check
    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        Log.i("Jalal", "checkDataBase()");

        SQLiteDatabase checkDb = null;

        try {
            String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "Error while checking db");
        }
        //Android doesn’t like resource leaks, everything should
        // be closed
        if (checkDb != null) {
            checkDb.close();
        }
        return checkDb != null;
    }

    //Method for copying the com.domain.sample.database
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
        Log.i("Jalal", "copyDataBase()");
        //Open a stream for reading from our ready-made com.domain.sample.database
        //The stream source is located in the assets
        InputStream externalDbStream = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        //Path to the created empty com.domain.sample.database on your Android device
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        //Now create a stream for writing the com.domain.sample.database byte by byte
        OutputStream localDbStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        //Copying the com.domain.sample.database
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = externalDbStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            localDbStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        //Don’t forget to close the streams
        localDbStream.flush();
        localDbStream.close();
        externalDbStream.close();
    }

    public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        Log.i("Jalal", "openDataBase()");
        final String  path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        if (database == null) {
            createDataBase();
            database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        }
        return database;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        Log.i("Jalal", "close");

        if (database != null) {
            database.close();
        }
        super.close();
    }
    // @Override
    // public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {}
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {}


  }
```

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: All that broken code is not needed with SQLiteAssetHelper.

Comment: hi @laalto   could you please give me a sample code using SQLiteAssetHelper the  above code was already working like this one https://github.com/khalid-hussain/HisnulMuslim/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/khalid/hisnulmuslim/database/ExternalDbOpenHelper.java on SDK 23 but there is issue on SDK 28

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be be over complicating matters. That is if you use a subclass of SQLiteAssetHelper you simply need to let the subclass do it's stuff. i.e. it will copy the database from the assets/databases folder as required.

As an example for a pre-existing database  `.../assets/databases/Data.db` and assuming using a singleton then :-

The subclass of the **`SQLiteAssetHelper`** *(`DatabaseOpenHelper` in this example)* could be :-

```
public class DatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Data.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public DatabaseOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
}
```

The class for the **`Singleton`** could be :-

```
public class DatabaseAccess {
    private SQLiteAssetHelper openHelper;
    private static SQLiteDatabase database;
    private static DatabaseAccess instance;


    private DatabaseAccess(Context context) {
        this.openHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(context);
    }

    /**
     * Return a singleton instance of DatabaseAccess.
     *
     * @param context the Context
     * @return the instance of DabaseAccess
     */
    public static DatabaseAccess getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new DatabaseAccess(context);
            database = instance.openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    /**
     * Get the SQLiteDatabase
     * @return the SQLiteDatabase
     */
    public SQLiteDatabase getDatabase() {
        return this.database;
    }
}
```

The invoking code (from `MainActivity` in this case) could then be along the lines of :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    SQLiteDatabase mDB;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        DatabaseAccess dba = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(this); // get DBAccess Instance
        mDB = dba.getDatabase(); //Get the database
        // use the database (list tables and indexes)
        Cursor csr = mDB.query("sqlite_master",
                null,
                null,
                null  ,
                null,
                null,
                "name"
        );

        StringBuilder tables = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder indexes = new StringBuilder();
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            String current_name = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("name"));
            String current_type = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("type"));
            switch (current_type) {
                case "table":
                    tables.append("\n\t").append(current_name);
                    break;
                case "index":
                    indexes.append("\n\t").append(current_name);
                    break;
            }
        }
        csr.close();
        Log.d("DB TABLES","Tables in the Database are :-" + tables.toString());
        Log.d("DB INDEXES","Indexes in the Database are:-" + indexes);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (mDB.isOpen()) {
            mDB.close();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Assuming that the doesn't currently exist, output would be along the lines of :-

```
07-01 00:55:18.567 1436-1436/? W/SQLiteAssetHelper: copying database from assets...
    database copy complete
07-01 00:55:18.571 1436-1439/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 227K, 10% free 6168K/6791K, paused 1ms+0ms, total 8ms
07-01 00:55:18.615 1436-1436/? I/SQLiteAssetHelper: successfully opened database Data.db
07-01 00:55:18.615 1436-1436/? D/DB TABLES: Tables in the Database are :-
        android_metadata
        data
07-01 00:55:18.619 1436-1436/? D/DB INDEXES: Indexes in the Database are:-
```

If the database does exist then the output would be along the lines of :-

```
07-01 00:56:52.502 1483-1483/? I/SQLiteAssetHelper: successfully opened database Data.db
07-01 00:56:52.502 1483-1483/? D/DB TABLES: Tables in the Database are :-
        android_metadata
        data
07-01 00:56:52.502 1483-1483/? D/DB INDEXES: Indexes in the Database are:-
```

- i.e. no `W/SQLiteAssetHelper: copying database from assets...
      database copy complete`

Should the asset file not exist or there be another issue then the output would be along the lines of :-

```
07-01 00:58:57.004 1552-1552/? W/SQLiteAssetHelper: copying database from assets...
07-01 00:58:57.004 1552-1552/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
07-01 00:58:57.004 1552-1552/? W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa6223288)
07-01 00:58:57.004 1552-1552/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{examples.mjt.sqliteassethelperexample/examples.mjt.sqliteassethelperexample.MainActivity}: com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper$SQLiteAssetException: Missing databases/Dataaaaa.db file (or .zip, .gz archive) in assets, or target folder not writable
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper$SQLiteAssetException: Missing databases/Dataaaaa.db file (or .zip, .gz archive) in assets, or target folder not writable
        at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
        at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:315)
        at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:289)
        at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.copyDatabaseFromAssets(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:436)
        at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.createOrOpenDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:400)
        at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:176)
        at examples.mjt.sqliteassethelperexample.DatabaseAccess.open(DatabaseAccess.java:45)
        at examples.mjt.sqliteassethelperexample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

- In this case instead of **Data.db** the file was change to **Dataaaaa.b** to force this issue.

**As you see there is no need to write your own code for checking and copying the database.**

---

Furthermore you don't get the confusing dump when the check for the database already existing doesn't find the database as per :-

```
06-29 14:56:20.811 19467-19467/com.domain.sample E/SQLiteLog: (14) cannot open file at line 36667 of [0c55d17973]
    (14) os_unix.c:36667: (2) open(/data/user/0/com.domain.sample/databases/quotes.sqlite3) -  06-29 14:56:20.812 19467-19467/com.domain.sample E/SQLiteDatabase: Failed to open database '/data/user/0/com.domain.sample/databases/quotes.sqlite3'.
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14 SQLITE_CANTOPEN): Could not open database
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:211)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:195)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:503)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:204)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:196)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:880)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:865)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:766)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:714)
        at com.domain.sample.database.ExternalDbOpenHelper.checkDataBase(ExternalDbOpenHelper.java:93)
        at com.domain.sample.database.ExternalDbOpenHelper.createDataBase(ExternalDbOpenHelper.java:70)
        at com.domain.sample.database.ExternalDbOpenHelper.openDataBase(ExternalDbOpenHelper.java:133)
        at com.domain.sample.database.ExternalDbOpenHelper.<init>(ExternalDbOpenHelper.java:48)
        at com.domain.sample.database.ExternalDbOpenHelper.getInstance(ExternalDbOpenHelper.java:32)
        at com.domain.sample.loader.AbstractQueryLoader.<init>(AbstractQueryLoader.java:14)
        at com.domain.sample.loader.QuoteGroupLoader.<init>(QuoteGroupLoader.java:17)
        at com.domain.sample.QuoteGroupActivity.onCreateLoader(QuoteGroupActivity.java:154)
        at android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl.createAndInstallLoader(LoaderManagerImpl.java:370)
        at android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl.initLoader(LoaderManagerImpl.java:404)
        at com.domain.sample.QuoteGroupActivity.onCreate(QuoteGroupActivity.java:107)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7131)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7122)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2882)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3037)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1797)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6642)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 06-29 14:56:20.812 19467-19467/com.domain.sample
```